# Change page in browser after end of controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can i change page in browser, after end of controller?
I tryed this:

Html/JS code:

```
<form>
    <button type="submit" onclick="abc()">123</button>
</form>
<script>
function abc()
    {
        $.post("/", "abc", function () {
        });
    }
</script>
```

ASP.NET MVC Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(dynamic response)
        {
            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() + "/Home/OtherPage");
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what you mean by end of controller ?

Comment: @Shyju end of controller method.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(dynamic response)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("OtherPage", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: After this my page reload, but not redirect to OtherPage.

Comment: it should redirect to otherpage. this is what it's designed to do. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: verify that the target controller and action are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution -

Your Action should be like this -

```
    public ActionResult RedirectMe()
    {
        return new JsonResult() { Data = "http://www.google.com", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

Then your JQuery POST should be -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("RedirectMe")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

When you Click the button, you will be redirected to the Google. You have to make sure you construct a proper URL (instead of google) and send it back.

If you want to pass some parameters to Action, then follow this way -

```
public ActionResult RedirectMe(string id)
{
    return new JsonResult(){ Data = "http://www.google.com", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
```

Finally your JQuery POST should be -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function submitForm() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("RedirectMe")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: "This is my parameter"}),
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. But I dont understand one thing. How can I transfer data to "/Home/OtherPage", if I'm using this method?

Comment: @EXTRAM pass it in QueryString like `/Home/Otherpage?param=123`. Thats the reason I said you need to construct your URL properly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect to another page in your client code, You may send the new url in a JSON response and use `window.location.href` property to naviagate to that.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(dynamic response)
{
    //Do your other work

    string newUrl=Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() + "/Home/OtherPage";
    //It may be better to use the Helper methods to get the url.

    return Json(new { NewUrl=newUrl);
}
```

In your ajax call

```
$.post("YourURLHEre",{ response :YourDataHere},function(res){
   window.location.href=res;
});
```